# Upgraded from react-native-firebase to @react-native-firebase but still getting an error: RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I moved from using react-native-firebase to @react-native-firebase but i am getting an error with regards to RNFirebase. I am also using XCode 15. Also, when i do react-native run-ios in the terminal, it works. But when I run on XCode, it does not.

my PodFile:

```
# Created by react-native-pod
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'myapp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'

  target 'myappTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

my package.json contains this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@callstack/reanimated-arc": "^0.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.4.3",
```

I kept on seeing that RNFirebase is found in react-native-firebase package but i already have @react-native-firebase

Any way to build on XCode properly and not crash?

Comment: i think you should have to clean the project by (command ⌘ + shift + k) and then run build by (command ⌘ + shift + b). I think it resolves your issue